# How to make a border in css that is actually on the very edges

Tags: html, css, browser, border

I'm trying to make a CSS border that is on the very edge of the page.
So far I have:

```
body{ 
color:#008000;
background-color: blanchedalmond;
border: 5px solid #000080;
}
```

This does create a border, however, between that border and the sides, top, and bottom, of my browser, there's another small area [equal size for all sides] that is just the background color of the page. I want this area to go away. I'm using Chrome, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
body{ 
color:#008000;
background-color: blanchedalmond;
border: 5px solid #000080;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Yup, this fixes it. The answers are all pretty much the same, so I just picked at random. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, as well:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the padding/margin if it exists...

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's the body margin, that is unless that isn't your complete css

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```